# Processing 4 - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: python, java, processing, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to use `processing-4.0b6-linux-x64` for Ubuntu 20.

It works well with Java and p5.js. Unfortunately it does not work at all with Python.

When I run the app from the terminal by `./processing`, a sort of warning appears from the command line:

> does not exist
> created registry at port 8220
> could not create registry; assume it's already created

Anyway, the GUI works well, but running a very simple code:

```py
def setup():
    size(800, 600)
    
def draw():
    pass
```

does not work and I receive the following list of errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String processing.app.Sketch.getMainProgram()'
    at jycessing.mode.run.PdeSketch.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.mode.PyEditor.runSketch(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.mode.PyEditor.handleRun(Unknown Source)
    at jycessing.mode.PyToolbar.handleRun(Unknown Source)
    at processing.app.ui.EditorToolbar$1.actionPerformed(EditorToolbar.java:135)
    at processing.app.ui.EditorButton.mousePressed(EditorButton.java:191)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6623)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4572)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I have java

```
openjdk 11.0.13 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and javac

```
javac 11.0.13
```

already installed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a regression in the beta 6 release: a method was removed that Python Mode was still using.

It was already reported [here](https://github.com/processing/processing4/issues/409) and fixed for beta 7 (when that's available), or if you build from source.

Answer (score 0):

Processing 4.0b6 runs on Java 17.0.2, which is bundled with the app. You shouldn't use your own java runtime.

Assuming that this is still a beta, and devs experience [similar issues](https://github.com/processing/processing4/issues/408),
I would recommend you ensure that is run on bundled java.
Maybe try on another platform.
And finally, submit an issue to their GitHub

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *I would recommend you ensure that is run on bundled java.*

Comment: Anyway, `processing-3.5.4-linux64` does work.